# Respond to user who made server request

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Say for example that a user made a log in request and I want the server to emit a message to him, but nobody else. How would I accomplish such a thing using socket.io? Here is what I have so far:

```
var users = []; // List of usernames

io.on("connection", handleIO);

function handleIO(socket){
    console.log('Client connected...');

    socket.on('login', function(data){ // When user presses login button
        users.push(data);

    });
}
```

How can I then send the user who made the 'login' request a socket event. Is there a `socket.emit` that just emits to the user who made the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `.emit()` on the incoming socket:

```
var users = []; // List of usernames
io.on("connection", handleIO);

function handleIO(socket){
    console.log('Client connected...');

    socket.on('login', function(data){ // When user presses login button
        users.push(data);
        socket.emit("Welcome!");
    });
}
```